# Check if a document exists in the collection, if not add a new document

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using MongoDB with PHP to store songs which users add via a basic form. The collection I created looks like below.

```
$object = array(
    "trackName" => "Sju sorger",
    "artistName" => "Veronica Maggio",
    "albumName" => "Satan i Gatan",
     );
$collection->save($object);
```

What I trying to accomplish is to check if a song is already in the collection. If the song user trying to add is not already in the collection, it'd be added. If it is already in the collection, a notification stating that the song is already in the collection will be displayed.

I'm relatively new to MongoDB but I assume I can check if the song is already in the collection by checking the **_id** of the document. But I have no idea on how to accomplish that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this approach.

```
  <?php
    try {
      // open connection to MongoDB server
      $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

      // access database
      $db = $conn->test;

      // access collection
      $collection = $db->items;

      // GET TRACK NAME
      $trackname = 'placetracknamehereifsearchingbytrackname';
      // retrieve existing document
      $criteria = array(
        'trackName' => trackname ,
      );
      $doc = $collection->findOne($criteria);

      if(!empty($doc) {
         echo 'Data Already Exist';
      } else {
  // insert a new document
  $object = array(
    "trackName" => "Sju sorger",
    "artistName" => "Veronica Maggio",
    "albumName" => "Satan i Gatan",
     );
     $collection->save($object);
     echo 'Added Successfully!';
}
      // disconnect from server
      $conn->close();
    } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
      die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
      die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

use this resource for further.

[Mongo Resource](http://devzone.zend.com/1730/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-php/)

Answer (score 0):

As to date, the best option is to use `upsert` option of the `update` operation. This feature allows for insert OR update behavior in MongoDB and is atomic - the example above is not. For whether or not the document in question was replaced you can observe `nUpserted` value of `WriteResult`

See

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult.nUpserted

Although very old, this question still pops up in search results and I have seen this linked previously.